# Mailchimp API - Pagination not working for lists

Tags: python, mailchimp

I'm trying to make a generic `python` script to retrieve an arbitrary number of lists through the `mailchimp` api. However, the "pagination" feature isn't working. There are sixteen lists in my account and whatever value I try for `offset=n&count=n`, I get only those 16 records. Here is part of my code that fetches the lists:

```
#FETCH ALL REPORTS
baseurl = "https://" + dc + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/"
request = urllib2.Request(baseurl + "reports/")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, key)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
try:
    output = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    data =  json.loads(output)
except:
    print "Error occurred. Make sure you entered the correct api key"
    exit()
createfile("allcampaigns.json", output)

psize, i = 10, 0
while(True):
    list_url = baseurl + "lists" + '?offset=' + str(psize * i) + '&count=' + str(psize) 
    #list_url = baseurl + "lists+ '?offset=' + str(psize * i) + '&count=' + str(psize) 
    print list_url
    request = urllib2.Request(list_url)
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, key)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    output = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    createfile("alllists.json", output)
    #print output
    data.update(json.loads(output))
    cnt = len(data)
    print cnt, " lists retrieved."
    if cnt<psize: break #cnt could also be zero if no records are returned
    i += 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Your code looks like it's supposed to return all 16 lists. What are you expecting it to do instead?

Comment: No it doesn't. I've included the `psize` variable to control pagination which is set at `10`. So, I should get 10 rows in the first request and other 6 rows subsequently, not all 16 at once.

Comment: What's the value of `list_url`? MailChimp's pagination is working fine for me in v3.0. It'd be useful to see the actual request you're sending and MailChimp's actual response. Maybe send the request through a [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/) proxy?

Comment: If you do run it through us, you can easily share the result: https://www.runscope.com/docs/sharing

Comment: Thanks, @JohnSheehan-Runscope. Sorry, the issue was at my end only, nothing wrong with mailchimp API. On the returned json object, I was counting `len(data)` instead of the `len(data.lists)` object. Fixed it and started working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be in my code only, there was nothing wrong with the `mailchimp api`, of course. On the returned `json` object, I was counting len(data) instead of the len(data.lists) object. Fixed it and started working!